# How to get server's public IP address using PHP?

Tags: php, ip

I need to get Public IP address of the system using PHP. I tried the following function:

```
function get_server_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

But, I got only the localhost IP `127.0.0.1`. I am in need of the server's public IP address. What function is available in PHP to get my public IP address which I get from this site: `http://www.whatismyip.com/`

Comment: That is your ip address when testing locally

Comment: @JohnConde so, can't I get the global IP address ?

Comment: You will get the IP that made the request. If you do a request locally `127.0.0.1` _is_ your IP. If you can route the traffic outside of local network somehow you will see an external IP.

Answer (score 14):

It is not possible to get Your IP address on that way if you run web server on same machine or local LAN where you run your browser client, you will always get local IP address.

If You still want to get Your public address from PHP script, on *nix servers which runs in same network as your browser client, you can get it via command like this:

```
$myPublicIP = trim(shell_exec("dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"));
echo "My public IP: ".$myPublicIP;
```

Comment: And it resolves extremely fast! Thanks!

Comment: This works 100% thank you. My PC is running XAMPP on Ubuntu 20.04 X64