# Configure Symfony's trusted proxies for jwilder/nginx-proxy

Tags: docker, symfony, nginx, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am trying to get client IP with `$request->getClientIp();` and it returns `172.19.0.2`, but that is not my public IP.

I stumbled upon [this doc to set up trusted proxies](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/deployment/proxies.html) so I tried doing like this:

```
// web/app_dev.php
// ...
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
// tell Symfony about your reverse proxy
Request::setTrustedProxies(['172.19.0.0/8'], Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL);
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
// ...
```

But that did not fix the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your app deployed on some web hosting or placed on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

"Public IP"? As explained in "[How can I get client real ip address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71561449/6309)"

> Typically a Public IP address can be found when your service is reached over the internet.
>
> Your PHP app has no clue about your public IP as it is in the private network. Public IP is assigned to you by your ISP/Router. Router NATs the private IPs so only 1 IP is allocated to your private network.

That means you would need to rely to your reverse proxy (NGiNX in your case) to populate correctly `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, which [you can try and read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24275009/6309):

```
$IParray=array_values(array_filter(explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])));
```

Or use [this `GetClientIP()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74079856/6309), which would check for:

- `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP`
- `HTTP_X_REAL_IP`
- `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`
- `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`
- `HTTP_X_FORWARDED`
- `HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP`
- `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR`
- `HTTP_FORWARDED`
- `REMOTE_ADDR`

Again, it depends on what the internet-facing reverse-proxy has set.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you use docker container + nginx proxies. So, here seems, IP send to software incorrectly. In that case, you can use nginx configuration to pass whole headers from client to the container (port). Let's mean that, we have software (container) which work over 9001 port in localhost. Then we must set configuration like that:

```
 location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
         proxy_set_header        Host               $host;
         proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```